# Avoid tiny AlertDialog with TextField in Landscape

Tags: flutter

I have an `AlertDialog` with a `TextField` as its `content`. But when the device is in Landscape, this happens:

[image]

How can I avoid this? `AlertDialog` already has its own paddings that can't be changed.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that Bottom overflow error.
This is because of lack of space in Landscape mode.
Just wrap your content inside SingleChildScrollView and it might work.

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (_){
              return AlertDialog(content: SingleChildScrollView(child: TextFormField()),);
            });
```

Comment: That makes the content of the dialog scrollable. But there isn't even any content visible from this size. I tried to make the keyboard show full screen, but flutter can't do that